# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twitter.algebird.CMSHasher

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to use [skew join](https://github.com/tresata/spark-skewjoin) in my project. I have all the dependencies added in my project but I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twitter.algebird.CMSHasher error even though I have added its dependency in my POM file. I suspect there is some version issues but I am not able to fix it even after trying different versions. Any idea what might be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with building the jar of the project. All I had to was to build a jar with dependencies and it solved the problem. Voila !